# Span content in textarea

Tags: javascript

```
<style>    
    .span1{
         left:10px;
     }

    .span2{
         left:20px;
     }
</style>

<span class='span1'> 1 </span> 
<span class='span2'> 2 </span>
```

I want to display the above content in textarea, in need a regex where I can replace `<span>` tags with `&nbsp;` so that the content in the textarea are correctly shown

It is for text editor where i would like to place certain key words automatically aligned. I am using a textarea in hidden state. When the user alters the code in div it is reflected in to the textarea in the div the code is heighlighting with different colors using css. I want the css tags 1 to be removed and replace 1 10 at the place i wanted in textarea so that when the file is saved, it will be submitted in the correct format.

Comment: @Downvoters: This is the first question of the OP at SO. Please say what is wrong with the question in your opinion to help him ask a better way intead of simply clicking a button.

Comment: please elaborate your question in batter way, are you looking for javascript/jquery to do this?.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if I understood you well, but correct me if I am wrong. The code uses [jQuery](http://jquery.com):

```
var shiftStep = 10,
    output = '';

$('span').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this),
        value = $this.text(),
        leftOffset = $this.css('left').slice(0, -2),
        finish = Math.floor(leftOffset / shiftStep);

    for (var i = 0; i < finish; i += 1) {

        /*
         * '&nbsp;' will be displayed as '&nbsp;'
         * in textarea, so use ' ' (space)
         */ 
        output += ' ';
    }

    output += value + '\n';
});

$('#output').val(output);
```

Additionally, you will have to change your CSS slightly.

The working result: http://jsfiddle.net/xrzNB/1/